# Moment.js with ReactJS (ES6)

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am new to Moment.js and using ReactJS (ES6) for my project. How can I use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format a date?

I want to format `post.date` in the below mentioned loop.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { 
            this.props.data.map((post,key) => 
                <div key={key} className="post-detail">
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <p>{post.date}</p>
                    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}}></p>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you bundling with webpack or browserify?

Comment: Is moment installed to your app via npm? and if so, you just need to import it in and use it like you would in normal javascript

Comment: @DavinTryon I am using webpack

Comment: @erichardson30 How can I use moment js functions in HTML loop.?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Since you are using webpack you should be able to just `import` or `require` moment and then use it:

```
import moment from 'moment'

...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { 
            this.props.data.map((post,key) => 
                <div key={key} className="post-detail">
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <p>{moment(post.date).format()}</p>
                    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}}></p>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
...
```

Comment: Agreed. Or if you don't want the moment code to be within the JSX, create a format date function that simply returns the new formatted date and from the JSX do `<p>{this.formatDate(post.date)}</p>`

Comment: Worked for me, the only thing I would say is import it as 
`import * as moment from 'Moment'`

Answer (score 20):

I know, question is a bit old, but since am here looks like people are still looking for solutions.

I'll suggest you to use `react-moment` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment),

`react-moment` comes with handy `JSX`tags which reduce a lot of work. Like in your case :-

```
import React  from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

exports default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{this.props.dateToFormat}</Moment>
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds an entirely additional package to the project increasing bundle size. Why not just do:

<div>{moment(this.props.dateToFormat).format('YYYY/MM/DD')}</div>


?

Answer (score 15):

*I have Used it as follow and it is working perfectly.*

```
import React  from 'react';
import * as moment from 'moment'

exports default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
            <div>
              {moment(dateToBeFormate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
            </div>            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the other answers fail, importing it as

```
import moment from 'moment/moment.js'
```

may work.

Answer (score 5):

run `npm i moment react-moment --save`

you can use this in your component,

`import Moment from 'react-moment';`

```
const date = new Date();
<Moment format='MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'>{date}</Moment>
```

will give you sth like this :
[image]

Comment: This adds an entirely additional package to the project increasing bundle size. Why not just do: <div>{moment(this.props.dateToFormat).format('YYYY/MM/DD')}</div> ?

Answer (score 4):

So, I had to format this Epoch Timestamp date format to a legit date format in my ReactJS project. I did the following:

1. `import moment from 'moment'` -- given you have moment js installed via NPM, if not head to [this link](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/)
2. For Example :

   If I have an Epoch date timestamp like `1595314414299`, then I try
   this in a console to see the result -

```js
  var dateInEpochTS = 1595314414299
  var now = moment(dateInEpochTS).format('MMM DD YYYY h:mm A');
  var now2 = moment(dateInEpochTS).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
  console.log("NOW");
  console.log(now);
  console.log("NOW2");
  console.log(now2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Expected Output**

```
"NOW"
"Jul 21 2020 12:23 PM"
"NOW2"
"Tuesday, July 21st, 2020 12:23:34 PM"
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case i want getting timeZone of several country ,first install moment js

```
npm install moment --save
```

then install moment-timezone.js

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

then i import themn in my component like this

```
import moment from 'moment';
import timezone from 'moment-timezone'
```

then because iwant getting hour and minutes and second sepratly i do like this

```
<Clock minutes={moment().tz('Australia/Sydney').minute()} hour={moment().tz('Australia/Sydney').hours()} second={moment().tz('Australia/Sydney').second()}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with API, then you can use it as:

```
import moment from 'moment'
...

        this.state = {
            List: []
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }
    // Show List
    getData() {
        fetch('url')
            .then((response) => {
                response.json()
                    .then((result) => {
                        this.setState({ List: result })
                    })
            })
    }
this.state.List = 
this.state.List.map(row => ({...row, dob: moment(row.dob).format("YYYY/MM/DD")}))

...
```

Answer (score 1):

**import moment to your project**

```
 import moment from react-moment
```

**Then use it like this**

```
return(
<Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{post.date}</Moment>
);
```

Comment: Answers should contain a short explanation.

Comment: This adds an entirely additional package to the project increasing bundle size. Why not just do: <div>{moment(this.props.dateToFormat).format('YYYY/MM/DD')}</div> ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 import moment from 'moment';
 .....

  render() {
   return (
    <div>
        { 
        this.props.data.map((post,key) => 
            <div key={key} className="post-detail">
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                <p>{moment(post.date).calendar()}</p>
                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}}></p>
                <hr />
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
   );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To use momentjs in Reactjs , we need to use the "Formats dates,Relatives time, Calendar Time or Multiple Locale Support",
according to  your needs choose only one . [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)
For examples:

```
 {orders.map((item) => (
      <Accordion defaultExpanded={true}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls='panel1a-content'
          id='panel1a-header'
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>
            {moment(item.created).format('MMM Do YY')} return  // Aug 12th 21 --> using Format Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO! (MAGIC SOLUTION)
In order to have a placeholder you must set your state to null first in the SELECTED property so that placeholder would be displayed and after that state would be mount with date user will select from the input tag.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
function App(){
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
  
  return(
    <>
    <DatePicker
      placeholderText="Click to enter the start date"
      **selected={startDate===" " ? null : startDate}**
      onChange={(date) => new Date(setStartDate(date))}
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      
 
   />
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using moment in my react project

```
import moment from 'moment'

state = {
    startDate: moment()
};
render() {
    const selectedDate = this.state.startDate.format("Do MMMM YYYY");
    return(
     <Fragment>
       {selectedDate)
     </Fragment>
   );
}
```